# AJAX passing data string and image file to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

Is there a possibility to pass image file in one function with dataString?

I've got something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../insert.php",
        data:  dataString, 
        success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
        }
      });
```

and everything works fine. Except the image is not send to php, only the name - thats pretty obvious. But how to achieve that?

Comment: This question has been answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax

Comment: yes, but it's only about sending an image, not two types of data (image and string)

Comment: Ok, i've managed to make it trough this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [How to send image to PHP file using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax)

The accepted answer should send all inputs (string and file).

To add extra inputs, you can try:

```
var extraInput = document.createElement('input');
extraInput.type = 'text';
extraInput.name = 'name';
extraInput.value = '...';

formData.appendChild(extraInput);
```

Comment: Ok, i've made it trough this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060247/send-formdata-and-string-data-together-through-jquery-ajax