# Display PHP var in HTML (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm searching for the best solution to display information which I store in PHP variable (which I get from a MySQL DB).

I was thinking to use jQuery. My questions:

- With the input field I receive the number of the Member.
- I store a new variable called $imgMember with the img name.

Questions:

- I want to display this image each time a user enters a number at `<div class="boxImageMember">` (which I already validated through PHP and made a variable ($imgMember) of it.
- How should I access it? Do I need to store those variable with AJAX? Internal/external jQuery? Or do I need to think otherwise? Im stuck in my head.

Im totally stuck with the way I how to process this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
 <div class="header-content">
  <img src="img/logo-dqmih.png" width="60px">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="boxImageMember">HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY A USER IMAGE</div>
  <div class="boxInformationMember"></div>

  <form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="MemberNumberEntry" name="staffNumber">
   <button type="submit" name="action">
  </form>

</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#MemberNumberEntry").focus();

     $(document).on('submit',function(event, test){
       event.preventDefault(); // Don't refresh the page

       var MemberNumberEntry = $("#MemberNumberEntry").val();
       console.log(MemberNumberEntry);

       $(".boxImageMember" ).css("background-image", "url(../images/persons/NIT.jpg)"); // Change image (Not dynamic yet)

       $(".boxInformationMember" ).text("Hi Test, welcome!");

       // Reset value form entry
       $('#memberNumberEntry').val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: So you'd like to send the value from the input to the PHP script using jQuery and get the value?

Comment: @Mav, I think I'm way to much thinking, its killing me. How can I explain this: I just want to have a dynamic html page. If a person enters a code (personal code) it will show his/her image. I was thinking to do this with jQUERY as I think I am more flexibel with it. My jQuery file and PHP file al seperated. My current script won't proceed any PHP now as it does not fires of (because I use preventDefault). So Im very confused.

Comment: I see. So yeah, it's a fairly decent approach, I'll put in an answer shortly explaining how you can use jQuery AJAX to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery script would do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#MemberNumberEntry").focus();

 $(document).on('submit',function(event, test){
   event.preventDefault(); // Don't refresh the page

   var MemberNumberEntry = $("#MemberNumberEntry").val();
   //console.log(MemberNumberEntry);
       $.ajax({
            url: '/your-php-script.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                MemberNumberEntry: MemberNumberEntry
            },
            success: function(response){
                //If call goes well, you use the image here.
            }
        });
   $(".boxImageMember" ).css("background-image", "url(../images/persons/NIT.jpg)"); // Change image (Not dynamic yet)

   $(".boxInformationMember" ).text("Hi Test, welcome!");

   // Reset value form entry
   $('#memberNumberEntry').val('');
});
});
```

You're basically sending an [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request to your PHP script that will accept the image ID like a normal post request, using `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST`.

There are tonnes of options to configure with jQuery, you can look at the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For more information on working with images in PHP and AJAX, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax) answer is useful.

Comment: Thanks. The AJAX url, could this be the same file as my HTML/PHP? Or what is the best way?

Comment: The ajax URL doesn't usually have markup, it is quite common to have a dedicated folder for AJAX script files that only process AJAX requests. /ajax/userImage.php, for instance.