# Call to a member function getData() on null while uploading cropped image using Ajax in Symfony 4

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony-3.3, croppie

So here I'm cropping the image and sending to Symfony Controller...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
 enableExif: true,
  viewport: {
    width:200,
    height:200,
    type:'square' 
},
boundary:{
  width:300,
  height:300
}
});
$('#upload_image').on('change', function(){
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event) {
  $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
    url: event.target.result
  }).then(function(){
    console.log('jQuery bind complete');
  });
}
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
$('#uploadimageModal').modal('show');
});

$('.crop_image').click(function(event){
$image_crop.croppie('result', {
  type: 'canvas',
  size: 'viewport'

}).then(function(response){

  $.ajax({

    url: "{{ path('app_bundle_route') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'img': response},

    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success:  function(data){
           $('#uploadimageModal').modal('hide');
           $("#previewImg").attr('src', response);

    }
  });
 });
});

 });
```

Controller

```
        $file = $request->files->get('img');   

        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName);

        $imageEn->setImage($file);
        $em->persist($imageEn);
        $em->flush();
```

Did I make mistake in something? I'm trying to post an image from Ajax to Symfony 4 but it seems the controller is unable to grab image file sent from Ajax.
Can anyone help me with how should I send an image from Ajax to the controller?

Comment: in {'img': response}, => what is the response?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: You should use FormData in ajax post. Then only in controller you will get $request->files->get('img'); i.e: file req. Please refer this simple php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax

Comment: Should I pass response in formData??

Comment: var formData = new FormData();                                      formData.append('img', response);                same error..

Comment: what error has occuring?

Comment: Call to a member function getData() on null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172693/discussion-between-gopalakrishnan-and-john-stevenson).