# How to Send image data with other data to java backend with http post in JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, progressive-web-apps

IAM trying to develop a offline PWA app .I have a image blob data which I want to send to java backend.

```
function callAjax(data){
         $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: "./WQF00069/update.app",
             cache:false,
             async:false,
             params:data,
             data: {} ,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
            }).success(function(data) {
                Flash.create('info', ' Update Success Fully ', 'large-text');
      }).error(function(response){ 
                 console.dir(response);
                 Flash.create('danger','There is a  Problem.Contact With Administrator', 'large-text');

         });
    }
```

After send the image data in params no data receive in java backend.Please help

Comment: please provide clear information about your problem, some code, logs, etc..

Comment: Encode the image binary to base64 and set it as a field in the json. At the back end you can decode the base64 to binary to get the original image.

Comment: Can not send the base 64data through param .

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image to text-based encodings ( Personally I would use base64) and send it with a POST request to your backend Java API.

Comment: Thanks Ali sir but still problem .

Comment: when i encript the image data it comes a large string. Which is not send through ajax

Answer (score 0):

I am sending this image data through ajax to backend.I also conver it in base  64 encode. But still problem .I think large data can not send through ajax.Here is my full code

```
//***After click on upload button******************// 
     vm.upload= function(state_cd,dist_cd,blk_cd,pan_cd,src_typ_cd,src_cd,src_nm,m_lat_val_degree,m_long_val_degree,src_img,imageContent){
        var imageall=null;
        var fd=null;
         var blob=null;
         var url=null;
//***************imageContent blob content from indexd db  and transfer in image *******************************************************************//
         getImageUrlFromBlob(imageContent).then(function (result) {
             imageall = result.replace(/data:;base64,/, 'data:image/gif;base64,');
             //var block = imageall.split(";");
            // var realData = block[1].split(",")[1];
            // blob = b64toBlob(realData,"image/gif");
            // var reader = new FileReader();
            // reader.readAsText(blob);
             //var image= reader.result;
            var data={'mst.stateCd':state_cd,'mst.distCd':dist_cd,'mst.blkCd':blk_cd,'mst.panCd':pan_cd,'mst.userId':$rootScope.userId,'mst.srcTypCd':src_typ_cd,'mst.srcCd':src_cd,'mst.srcNm':src_nm,'mst.mLatValDegree':m_lat_val_degree,'mst.mLongValDegree':m_long_val_degree,'mst.srcImg':src_img,'mst.imageContent':imageall};


          callAjax(data);// send image data to backend throgh ajax 
         });
     }
//************************Ajax call*****************************************************//
    function callAjax(data){
         $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: "./WQF00069/update.app",
             cache:false,
             async:false,
             params:data,
             data: {} ,
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
            }).success(function(data) {
                Flash.create('info', ' Update Success Fully ', 'large-text');
      }).error(function(response){ 
                 console.dir(response);
                 Flash.create('danger','There is a  Problem.Contact With Administrator', 'large-text');

         });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form[name='uploader']").submit(function(e) {
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: "page.jsp",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    success: function (msg) {
      alert(msg)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

follow this [How to send image to PHP file using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164365/how-to-send-image-to-php-file-using-ajax)

Comment: Durgesh Kumar sir thanks. But Except of form data can i send image from font end to back end ??

Comment: have a try, i have not actually used this way,