# Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, html, css, database, string

Please help me to solve this problem.

**

```
public function uploadPhoto($file)
    {
        if(!empty($file)){
            $fileTempPath=$file['tmp_name'];
            $fileName=$file['name'];
            $fileType=$file['type'];
            $fileNameCmps=explode('.',$fileName);
            $fileExtension=strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
            $newFileName=md5(time().$fileName) . '.' .
            $fileExtension;
            $allowedExtn=["png","jpg","jpeg"];
            if(in_array($fileExtension,$allowedExtn))
            {
                $uploadFileDir=getcwd().'/uploads';
                $destFilePath=$uploadFileDir . $newFileName;
                if(move_uploaded_file($fileTempPath,$destFilePath)){
                    return $newFileName;
                }
            }
    
        }
    }**
```

this is how I send data to parameters

** if($conf ==  $_SESSION['randomNum'])
{

```
                    //create object of user class 
                    require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\MEDICALCENTERPROJECT\app\libraries\User.php';
                    $obj = new User();
                    $obj->connect();
                     
                    $img = "";
                    if($pic == "")
                    {
                        $img = "null";
                    }
                    else{
                        $img = $obj->uploadPhoto($pic);

                    }**
```

I tried many times to understand the error but I could not do. Here the error is shown in line 111
its mean  $fileTempPath=$file['tmp_name']; in this line. Please help me to solve this.

**this is how I sent data using ajax**

**$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#success").hide();


$("#con").click(function() {

    let confirm = $("#ccode").val();
    let isTrue = "false";
    let username = $("#pusername").val();
    let email = $("#pemail").val();
    let mobile = $("#pmobile").val();
    let addrs = $("#paddress").val();
    let id = $("#pidno").val();
    let pswd = $("#ppassword").val();
    let c_pswd = $("#pcpassword").val();
    let pic = $("#puserphoto").val();


    let data = new FormData("#addformSign");
    $.ajax({
        url: "./Patials/sendEmailVerifyCode.php", //"./Patials/ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
             conf: confirm,
            isTrue: isTrue,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            mobile: mobile,
            addrs: addrs,
            id: id,
            pswd: pswd,
             pic: pic,
         },

        success: function(response) {

            alert(response);

            if (response == confirm) {

                $("#emailCon").modal("show");
                $("#confirm").hide();
                $("#success").show();

            } else {

                $("#ccode").css({
                    "borderColor": "red",
                    "backgroundColor": "rgba(253, 127, 127, 0.5)"
                });
                $("#confirm").show();
                $("#errMsg").text("Invalid Code!");

            }



        },

        error: function(request, error) {
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log("Erro" + error);
            $("#confirm").show();
        },
    });


});
```

**

let confirm = $("#ccode").val(); this input field is not in the same form.

Comment: There are several things that looks weird with the code (like: $img = "null". Why do you make $img a string with the value "null" instead of making it null?). The problem is that the value you have in $pic is a string. Not the actual file content. Where does $pic come from?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for comment for this problem. I put $img = "null" because of when I get the data from data base I can use other image to profile who did not upload their photo that is why I do so. And $pic is come from ajax

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "./Patials/sendEmailVerifyCode.php", //"./Patials/ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                conf: confirm,
                isTrue: isTrue,
                username: username,
                email: email,
                mobile: mobile,
                addrs: addrs,
                id: id,
                pswd: pswd,
                pic: pic,
            }, 

this is the ajax code "pic" is come from here. Please help me !!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are sending string as `$pic` value. It has to be some sort of array. Make sure you are sending the file correctly with Ajax. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21164512/19130814) Debug by examining the real-time value of the variable using PHP's `var_dump` function.

The way to solve errors without internet (without asking anyone) is to search for the real-time value of the variable. You can do this in php with the `var_dump`/`var_export`/`echo`/`print` functions.

Make sure you provide enough information to the other party when asking questions. I don't know how you send data with Ajax. It's impossible for me to get the same error as you. You should ask the same in a way that I can provide or imagine in my own setting.

The error you get is `TypeError`, that is, you can fix this error by checking the data you send and the data you receive.

---

UPDATE:

What you need to be careful about is that all the `<input>` elements you want to send are in the `<form>`.

you can try like that.

```
$("#con").click(function() {
  let confirm = $("#ccode").val();

  let yourFormData = new FormData("#addformSign"); // all sended element must be inside this form

  $.ajax({
    url: "./Patials/sendEmailVerifyCode.php", //"./Patials/ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: yourFormData,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
      if (response == confirm) {
        $("#emailCon").modal("show");
        $("#confirm").hide();
        $("#success").show();
      } else {
        $("#ccode").css({
            "borderColor": "red",
            "backgroundColor": "rgba(253, 127, 127, 0.5)"
        });
        $("#confirm").show();
        $("#errMsg").text("Invalid Code!");
      }
    },
    error: function(request, error) {
      console.log(arguments);
      console.log("Erro" + error);
      $("#confirm").show();
    },
  });
});
```

---

If the above code does not solve the problem, make sure that you send the values ​​of the input fields you sent correctly with ajax.

For example, you need to use the following line as

```
let pic = $('#puserphoto').prop('files')[0];
```

instead of

```
let pic = $("#puserphoto").val();
```

---

also `$_FILES` is used to receive the file sent with the `POST` method.

```
$pic = $_FILES['pic']
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question please check it and can you help me to solve it correctly

Comment: when I put $pic = $_FILES['pic'] like this with  $pic = $_FILES['pic']  it always says "Undefined array key "pic"  "  but if I change the type of input as "text" instead "file" it does not say like that. Can you tell me what's wrong with me.